# Using Raspberry Pi with Canon EOS 7D

Tags: canon, timelapse, canon-7d, storage

I'm going on holiday soon and I'm going to be taking my Canon EOS 7D with me. I will be taking my CF cards with me for general shooting, but I want more storage for time lapses. I believe this is possible by connecting a Raspberry Pi to it, and then connecting an external hdd to the Pi.

I was wondering what tutorials I could follow to link this all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Raspberry Pi is just an ARM-based computer you can run Linux distributions that compile on ARM (v6). There is a guide [here](http://www.davidhunt.ie/raspberry-pi-in-a-dslr-camera/) where photographer David Hunt transforms his old broken battery grip (although this one was for a 5D mark II) into embedded computer that does what you're looking for among other things that can be useful for time lapse such as acting as an intervalometer and also the possibility to wake the camera up through the shutter release port (something that can't be done through USB).

If you build it you can also do wireless tethered shooting by connecting a WiFi adapter to the USB port of the Raspberry Pi and remote control it from smartphones and computers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I remember reading the article on David Hunt's website a while back. Do you have any idea what script/package on Raspbian I can use to check for new images and copy across as he does in his tutorial?

Comment: @JakeNeal This is borderline off topic, but you can use gphoto2 http://gphoto.org/ to remote control the camera and to transfer them to your Raspberry Pi. If you want GUI you can use the official gtkam or other clients such as digiKam or Shotwell, but I don't know how well they will perform on this hardware and you might be better of going CLI. Regarding the script you should use you can follow this part of the manual http://www.gphoto.org/doc/manual/using-gphoto2.html, if that isn't enough I suggest you start a new thread the sister site http://stackoverflow.com/ since it's way off topic here

Answer (score 0):

It might also be worthwhile to look into something like [DSLR Controller](http://dslrcontroller.com/guide-wifi_mr3040.php), an android app that can remote control your Canon camera. You can use a (specific) [MiFi device, a TL-MR3040](http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-TL-MR3040-Portable-Battery-Wireless/dp/B00842KJOS/) to remote-control the camera (as @Hugo suggested as well).

The app has time lapse functions, which might (or might not) be sufficient for your use. But there are [alternatives](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dslr.dashboard) if the app above is not to your liking.

Comment: Note that Jake asked for a device that lets him connect a external HDD to save the images to that directly. The reason I told him about the controller features was just that he was doing time lapse and it could be a nice bonus.

Comment: @Cornelius - Thanks for the suggestion - I remember reading something on DSLR Controller for android a while back. I have my time lapse part of it sorted though